# create points parallel to triangle corners

Tags: math, three.js, geometry

Let's say I have this triangle (dark blue) and I know it's vertices (red):
(1,3,0)
(0,4,0)
(-1,3,0)

Now I want to create new points (yellow) above their vertices but parallel to the triangle. In this case it is easy: just add to the y value and you got it.

[image]

But what if the triangle is not straight up? for example: 
(1,3,0)
(0,4,1)
(-1,3,0)

[image]

I got its n-Vector (green line) and I think I have to use it to create these parallel points, but I don't know how...I am looking for a way to do this to multiple triangles programmatically that are positioned in all kind of ways. Any idea?

**@Ben Whitmore**

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,4,1);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(1,3,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(-1,3,0);

var c = new THREE.Vector3( );
c.crossVectors( v2, v3 ) // { x: 0, y: -0, z: 6 }
c.normalize() // { x: 0, y: -0, z: 1 }

sphere.position.set( ??? );`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to find a direction vector that is perpendicular to the plane of the triangle. This can be easily derived from the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two of the edges of the triangle, the result then normalised to a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).

There are of course two directions that vector can take, to be perpendicular to the plane: it can be pointing "above" the plane or "below" the plane. Which direction you get will depend on the clockwise/anticlockwise directions of the triangle's edge vectors. If it's not the direction you want, simply invert it.

Comment: Thanks, but at what position should I set the sphere now?
(I can't add formatted code here, so I edited my post, please take a look)

Comment: You need to take your cross product from the edge vectors, not the absolute positions of the vertices:

c.crossVectors( v2 - v1, v3 - v2 )

Then after normalizing (and scaling, presumably), add the result onto v1 to get a point offset from v1; add to v2 to get a point offset from v2; etc.
I presume your "sphere" is one of the yellow points.